# eclipse outline for angular sources with javascript developer tools

Tags: javascript, angularjs, eclipse

I use Aptana Studio and AngularJS.

When I open a javascript file, which I define a controller or a service, outline section is empty.

is there a way or trick to see list of variables/functions in the outline, which are defined in that controller or service?

for example

```
myApp.controller('myAppController', function($scope){ 
   var abc = {}; 
   $scope.var1 = abc; 
   var funcA = function(){
      return false
   }; 
   $scope.funcB = function(){};
};
```

is it there a way to see abc, var1, funcA and funcB in outline?

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: What outline? Your question is confusing..

Comment: Aptana uses its own plug-ins, not the Eclipse JavaScript Development Tools. Which one are you asking about?

Comment: @Dsafds Outline for functions and variable in project.

Comment: @nitind I use Aptana, but I installed JSDT too, just to try if it work on outlines. But it didnt help.

Answer (score 2):

I know question is about Aptana, but as your question is about too Angular and Eclipse and Outline, I suggest you that you try [AngularJS Eclipse](https://github.com/angelozerr/angularjs-eclipse/wiki/Getting-Started). It is based on [tern.jav](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Getting-Started)a and provides a [Tern Outline](https://github.com/angelozerr/tern.java/wiki/Tern-Outline-support):

[image]

Please note that tern.java extends the JSDT Editor and in the future version JSDT will give the capability to extend Outline. So Tern Outline will be removed and replaced with standard Outline.

Comment: Thanks. I installed eclipse mars and added angularjs-eclipse plugin. Tern Outline View works perfect.